# How to merge MySQL data

Tags: mysql

There are two schemas in MySQL. For example `db1` and `db2`.

They have same structure of tables and different data to each other.

Now I want to merge data on `db1` with data on `db2`.

I tried below:

1. `mysqldump` from `db1` with no drop table option.
2. Import dumpfile into `db2` to use RESOURCE command.

But it didn’t work, nothing was added?

Comment: Do db1.data and db2.data tables have the same structure?  Can you let us know more details about what options you used in mysqldump and mysql on import?

Comment: mysqldump –u root -–add-drop-table=false –p db1>db1.sql then connect to db2 and load db1.sql by \. db1.sql command.

Comment: Have you tried to load the data from outside, i.e. `mysql -u user -ppassword db2 < db1.sql`  Also, please check the first few lines of db1.sql file for commands like `USE db1;`.  If you find it - remove.

Comment: I tried.The eesult was ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 24: Table 'myTable' already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `mysqldump` command with the following option `--no-create-info`.  This will prevent `mysqldump` from writing the `CREATE TABLE` in the dump file.  You could also use `--insert-ignore` option to prevent from loading duplicate values (if any).

**UPDATE 1**

If both of your schemas reside on the same server, you could always use the `INSERT ... SELECT` command.  For example:

```
INSERT INTO db2.table2 (table2_col1, table2_col2, table2_col3)
SELECT table1_col1, table1_col2, table1_col3
FROM db1.table1
WHERE ...
```

Comment: mysqldump –u root -–nocreate-info --insert-ignore –p db1>db1.sql It worked well.I got merge tablse.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using host name :

`mysqldump -h hostname –u root -–add-drop-table=false –p db1>db1.sql ...`

Comment: This way also usefull.Thank you.But tell me why -h option is needed?

Comment: default its take the localhost as host name . If we have the another new host name, We should to define it. Mostly this cause the problem at live site.

Comment: Actually, I have already face the problem without host name on live site. At local it was running right without host name.

Comment: Sounds strange .Actually, I use localhost in my command that was mysqldump -h localhost –u root -–add-drop-table=false –p db1>db1.sql and I don't have any another host.But thanks anyway.